# Python Open Cv. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, opencv3.0

I doing Image processing, I want to remove some part from image and replace with another one background image for that I defined patch which equals to background one. please help me.

```
def replace(self, patch, show_it=True):
    mask = self._buildMask(self.image)
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    self.image[mask !=0 ]= patch[mask !=0]
    #print(mask.dtype)
    #self.image[mask != 0] = patch[mask != 0]
```

I got Error like this

```
self.image[mask !=[0] ]= patch[mask !=[0]]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Thank you

Comment: Either `self.image[mask !=0 ]` or `patch[mask !=0]` have value `None`. You can add an if statement checking if their value is none before performing `self.image[mask !=0 ]= patch[mask !=0]`

Comment: Sorry, Can you please give the clarity on this. @FBSO

Comment: Before `self.image[mask !=0 ]= patch[mask !=0]` add: `if self.image[mask !=0 ] != None: `

Comment: Ok Fine ,I got this one `if self.image[mask !=0 ] != None:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() ` @FBSO

Comment: simply use `print()` to see values in variables - `print(self.images)` `print(patch)` `print(mask)` - and it should show you which one has value `None`

Comment: I tried to `print()`, I got `none` on `print(patch)` How can I solve this one. Because I am using this one `self.image[mask !=0 ]= patch[mask !=0]` and when I am using the `self.image[mask !=0 ] `  `# = patch[mask !=0]` its working. @furas

Comment: if you have `None` in `patch` then you have to find where you use this `replace(...)` and what value you have in argument. Problem is not inside this function but in value which you use as argument.

Comment: Ok Fine, I used the replace function here. `image_area.replace(patch=background, show_it=True)` @furas

Comment: so now check `print(background)` - probably it gives you `None`. You should find code which you use to create `background` and check why it gives `None`. If you read `background` from file then you have to check if you use correct path. If you read it with `cv2` then it doesn't shows error when file doesn't exists (or it can't read it) but it returns  `None`

Comment: Ok Thank you I got it..☺☺@furas